# How can I send javascript commands through inter/intranet?

Tags: javascript, alert

I received a pop up on my laptop which is connected to an intranet so I think that it came through that or the wifi since everyone is connected to the same one. It looked exactly like a simple javascript alert and popped up every half an hour no matter what site I was on.
I have tried using terminal (I'm on a mac air by the way) but that is not the same. 
I have literally looked all over the internet to find out how this was done and I can't figure it out. Please help me, maybe I am thinking about it in the wrong way but I just can't find anything like it.
Thanks :)

Comment: Disconnect from INTRANET and See if it stills pops up

Comment: Desktop notifications turned on in your browser?

Comment: I should add that it was happening to everyone connected to that wifi/intranet and it only happened for one week

Comment: First option: Did you install any browser plugins lately? One option would be to deactivate all browser plugins to see if the popup is still there. Second option: would be some kind of virus. Do you have a anti virus software?
For more help please let us know which browser you are using, what the popup says and what browser plugins you have installed.

Comment: I am using Chrome and the popup said "You've been sitting too long- get active" (don't ask- it was sport week). I don't know exactly what browser plugins are but I'm pretty sure it wasn't that because everyone would have had to have the same one- unless that is possible? If so, I should be able to do the same thing shouldn't I? I know that it was the tech guys that did it somehow.